# Create a hierarchichal data with python. based on a list of results

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, data-structures, hierarchical-data

I need to transform a lists of data in a hierarchical nested dictionary in python. A structure (father - child).

This is my data.

```
list_data = [
       {
           "id": 2,
           "father_id": 0,
           "desc": "Oficial de Negocios Senior",
           "name": "PEDRO MARTIN SOTO ROSALES"
       },
       {
           "id": 4,
           "father_id": 2,
           "desc": "Ejecutivo comercial",
           "name": "Adriana Paredez"
       },
       {
           "id": 5,
           "father_id": 2,
           "desc": "Ejecutivo comercial",
           "name": "Hugo Miranda"
       },
       {
           "id": 3,
           "father_id": 2,
           "desc": "Ejecutivo comercial",
           "name": "Mario Azcona"
       },
           {
                  "id": 6,
                  "father_id": 3,
                  "desc": "vendedor",
                  "name": "Diana Diaz"
              }
      ]
```

I already tried with this recursively function, and I get the structure right, but it aggregates 2 more copies of the first three children, that I really don't need it. The root father is the element with father_id = 0

```
def build(loc_key):

    children = {row['id']: {'name': row['name'], 'desc': row['desc'],
                                'child':[]} for row in list_data if row['father_id'] == loc_key}

    data = {}

    for key, value in children.items():
        data[key] = value
        for item in list_data:
            if item['father_id'] == key:
                data[key]['child'].append(build(key))
    return data

print(build(0))
```

This is basically what I need to get

```
data = {
       2: {'desc': 'Oficial de Negocios Senior',
          'name': 'PEDRO MARTIN SOTO ROSALES', 
          'child': 
              [
              {3: {'desc': 'Ejecutivo comercial', 
                  'name': 'Mario Azcona', 
                  'child': [
                            {6: {'desc': 'vendedor', 
                                'name': 'Diana Diaz', 
                                 'child': []}}]}, 
              4: {'desc': 'Ejecutivo comercial', 
                 'name': 'Adriana Paredez', 
                 'child': []}, 
              5: {'desc': 'Ejecutivo comercial', 
                 'name': 'Hugo Miranda', 
                 'child': []}
```

PD: I need to support it in a dynamic way, because users can add children on database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem lies in the fact that your `build` function takes as input a list of nodes, and does not operate on the individual nodes pairwise or in some other "smaller list" sort of way.  Therefore, recursion doesn't really make sense here.  OTOH, once you have built the tree (you are trying to build a tree by the way), then recursion would be very helpful with parsing the resulting structure.  However, it is not very helpful in building the tree.

Here is one way you can build the tree.  It is `O(n)` compute time and memory, but does store a couple more copies of the list in operation, so there may be some optimization possible there.

```
import pprint

list_data = [
       {
           "id": 2,
           "father_id": 0,
           "desc": "Oficial de Negocios Senior",
           "name": "PEDRO MARTIN SOTO ROSALES"
       },
       {
           "id": 4,
           "father_id": 2,
           "desc": "Ejecutivo comercial",
           "name": "Adriana Paredez"
       },
       {
           "id": 5,
           "father_id": 2,
           "desc": "Ejecutivo comercial",
           "name": "Hugo Miranda"
       },
       {
           "id": 3,
           "father_id": 2,
           "desc": "Ejecutivo comercial",
           "name": "Mario Azcona"
       },
       {
           "id": 6,
           "father_id": 3,
           "desc": "vendedor",
           "name": "Diana Diaz"
       }
]

def tree_structure(list_data):
    #build the requisite data structure in a "flat" way... you can initialize this "as you go" in the loop below if more optimization is needed.
    data = {row["id"]: {"desc": row["desc"], "name": row["name"], "child": {}} for row in list_data}
    root_id = None
    for row in list_data:
        if row["father_id"] != 0:
            data[row["father_id"]]["child"][row["id"]] = data[row["id"]] #note that this stores only a reference to the child dictionary, so it is O(1) memory
        else:
            root_id = row["id"] #we need this later
    return {root_id: data[root_id]}

pprint.pprint(tree_structure(list_data))
```

Comment: Note that `pprint` prints the `desc`, `name` and `child` in a different order than in your expected output.  This is because dictionaries have no intrinsic order, and the resulting data structures are identical.

Comment: Yes @Scott. I resolved on another way, but I think this is better than my method